# Firebase accessing user id code crashed on iphone 6s only?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

In my app I am uploading files to firebase storage. Now to create the filepath, I use below code

```
 let filePath = "\(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid)/\(Date())/\("tempImage")"
```

The strange thing is above code works on iPhone 6plus,5c,5s & also 6s simulator. But when I run on iPhone 6s (iOS 10.3.2) device code get crash because of optional nil value.

Please tell me what is wrong with my code?

Comment: From where are you fetching this "tempImage"?

Comment: I just creating path on firebase.Do you see any problem with code? As i mentioned it works with all devices except iphone 6s. I don't have 7 series phone so i can't test upon them

Comment: Provide extension like (.jpg) after file path.

Comment: If it was issue of file extension then why it is working fine on other device.I think it is related to firebase login

Comment: Are you successfully logged in on 6s? Please recheck if error is `nil` in your login completion block.